# How to create a 3 level vertical acordian menu with icons that open and close level 1 and level 2 whilst keeping the actual links clickable?

Tags: jquery, menu, accordion

I found this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/aCaEG/ from a previous post.

What I need is to have an icon for up down arrow like accordion where people click to open and close the menu levels but also have the actual links go to their destination rather than open the accordion.

Anyone got any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="#">level 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="#">level 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="#">level 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="#">level 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    margin:3px;
    border:1px solid red;  
}
ul ul{
    display:none;   
}
ul li:hover>ul{
    /*display:block;   */
}
```

JS:

```
$('li').click(function(ev) {
    $(this).find('>ul').slideToggle();
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight change in the javascript as well as the HTML:

HTML -- you want to add a span or link for your down arrow:

```
level 2 <span class="open">v</span>
```

JS:

```
$('li span.open').click(function(ev) {
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
    ev.stopPropagation();
});​
```

New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QhXR9/

Comment: OK yes that seems to do the job thanks new fiddle here with links:
http://jsfiddle.net/aCaEG/650/

But how do I make it so it uses a background image on the spans which has an arrow right and down and changes background position so arrow down when active and arrow right when not active?

thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aCaEG/652/ -- in the CSS uncomment the top 2 definitions and add in the images you want. The default one should be the right arrow and the `.opened` one should be the down arrow.